# what is the best way to expose the public lib function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I define a public function in public lib file `ResponseHandler.ts` like this:

```
const ResponseHandler = {
    responseSuccess:(response:any) => {
        if(response.statusCode === "200" && response.resultCode === "200"){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

export default ResponseHandler
```

then I expose the `ResponseHandler` in the public lib `index.ts` like this:

```
export * from "./src/net/rest/ResponseHandler";
```

when I use the `ResponseHandler` like this way:

```
import ResponseHandler  from "js-wheel/index";
```

shows error that:

```
File '/Users/xxxxx/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/node_modules/js-wheel/index.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

what is the property way to expose the ResponseHandler function? how to avoid this problem? is this the right way to expose function?

Comment: You don't need to include `/index`

Comment: this error still not fixed after remove the /index when import. @Rcdlb